# How can I synchronously access/call an object from multiple background workers

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I have an object on my main UI thread which sends serial commands to an arduino and I need to be able to access this object and have it send serial commands to the arduino in the order they are received from within two separate background workers.

I have searched around and found many methods to update a UI from multiple backgroundworkers but the problem is most of the solutions are geared at objects that were designed with multi threading in mind. I.e. you can do "GUIobject.Invoke(etc)".

```
        var driver = Periphrials.InitializeArduinoDriver();


        StillMonitor = new BackgroundWorker();
        StillMonitor.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        StillMonitor.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((state, args) =>

        {
        do
            {
                if (StillMonitor.CancellationPending)
                { break; }
                (driver.Send(new DigitalReadRequest(properties.StillLowSwitch)).PinValue.ToString() == "Low")      
            } while (true);
        });
```

The "driver.send......" part is what needs to be ran on the main thread but called from within the background workers.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2)-Class? Which does not need a GUI.

Comment: No I have not but after reading what it does this sounds like exactly what I was looking for. I'll give this a try and see if it works.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my answer, which provides an example using the Dispatcher Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Backgroundworker-Class then you can use the ProgressChanged-Event. This approach does not block the backgroundworker thread with each send-call.

```
var driver = Periphrials.InitializeArduinoDriver();

StillMonitor = new BackgroundWorker();
StillMonitor.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
StillMonitor.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
StillMonitor.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((state, args) =>
{
    do
    {
        if (StillMonitor.CancellationPending)
        { 
            break;
        }
        StillMonitor.ReportProgress(0); //Invokes the ProgressChanged Event on the thread the backgroundworker was created on.
    } while (true);
});
StillMonitor.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) => {
     (driver.Send(new DigitalReadRequest(properties.StillLowSwitch)).PinValue.ToString() == "Low")
}
```

If the thread should block with each send-call consider using the [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2)-Class (you need to add a reference to WindowsBase.dll):

```
using System.Windows.Threading; //WindowsBase.dll

//...

var driver = Periphrials.InitializeArduinoDriver();
Dispatcher driverDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher; //Gets the Dispatcher for the current Thread (or creates it)

StillMonitor = new BackgroundWorker();
StillMonitor.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
StillMonitor.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((state, args) =>
{
    do
    {
        if (StillMonitor.CancellationPending)
        { 
            break;
        }
        driverDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { //Invoke and block the Dispatcher
            (driver.Send(new DigitalReadRequest(properties.StillLowSwitch)).PinValue.ToString() == "Low")  
        }));    
    } while (true);
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! A quick suggestion for the answer though would be to highlight the fact that you need to reference windowsbase.dll. I spent a good 15 minutes trying to figure out why I couldn't create a dispatcher before I noticed the using statement you added.

Answer (score 0):

you can synchronize the driver.send call with a locking mechanism such as [lock-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement).

```
/////class
{
   private readonly object lockObject = new object();
   ....

   ///method
   var driver = Periphrials.InitializeArduinoDriver();

   StillMonitor = new BackgroundWorker();
   StillMonitor.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
   StillMonitor.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((state, args) =>
   {
      do
      {
         if (StillMonitor.CancellationPending)
         { break; }
         lock (lockObject)
         {
             //code here will run synchronously
             (driver.Send(new DigitalReadRequest(properties.StillLowSwitch)).PinValue.ToString() == "Low")      
         }
      } while (true);
  });
```

Comment: You might want to clarify 'synchronously', because the drive object is still accessed by the backgroundworker thread. I do not know if this is allowed by object.

Comment: When I say synchronously all I mean is that if both background workers in my application called the driver object at the same time I would want both events to happen but one should complete before the second starts to avoid overloading the arduino. This looks like it might be what I was looking for though.